# Trouble filtering data using where in bookshelf / knex

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am new to bookshelf.js and am using it for ORM in my node.js + MySQL project.
I am getting an error with this simple query. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
//Get reviews for a service - TESTED
app.get('/api/review/:serviceID?', function(req, res) {
  var serviceID = req.params.serviceID;
  console.log("Service ID: " + serviceID);
  new Review.query('where','serviceID','=', serviceID)
    .fetchAll()
    .then(function(reviews) {
        if (reviews!=null)
            res.send(reviews.toJSON());
        else
            res.send("No reviews found");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.send('An error occurred in fetching reviews for service '+ serviceID);
    });
});
```

Here review table has primary key as reviewID and serviceID as a foreign key.
This is the error message I am getting.

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'forge'
  at new Model.(anonymous function).Collection.(anonymous function
  (d:\PMF\node_modules\bookshelf\bookshelf.js:146:24)
  at app.get.serviceID (d:\PMF\app.js:121:15)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
  (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
  at next (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
  at Route.dispatch (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request
  (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
  at d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
  at param (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:340:14)
  at param (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:356:14)
  at Function.proto.process_params
  (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:400:3)
  at next (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
  at jsonParser (d:\PMF\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:96:40)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
  at trim_prefix (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
  at d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
  at Function.proto.process_params (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
  at next (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
  at jsonParser (d:\PMF\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:96:40)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
  at trim_prefix (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
  at d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
  at Function.proto.process_params (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
  at next (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
  at urlencodedParser (d:\PMF\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:84:40)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
  at trim_prefix (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
  at d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
  at Function.proto.process_params (d:\PMF\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
```

Comment: I have alternatively tried

    new Review({'serviceID': serviceID})
        .fetchAll()

but this gives me all the reviews ignoring the serviceID = $serviceID condition
I have tried 

    new Review({'serviceID': serviceID})
        .fetch()

but this gives me the first review where serviceID=$serviceID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Review` constructor call is missing the parenthesis: the code should be `new Review().query...` instead of `new Review.query...`.

As a side note, this simpler way of writing the query should work:

```
return new Review().where('serviceID', serviceID).fetchAll()
```